# Return an FSharpFunc from F# to C#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I want to write a function in F#, that exposes the following type signature to C#:

```
public static FSharpFunc<FSharpFunc<Unit,Unit>,Unit> foo(Action<Action> f)
```

In F# I tried writing:

```
let foo (f : Action<Action>) : ((unit -> unit) -> unit) = ...
```

But that produces the C# signature:

```
public static void foo(Action<Action> f, FSharpFunc<Unit,Unit> x)
```

The F# has treated my code equivalently to:

```
let foo (f : Action<Action>) (g : unit -> unit) : unit = ...
```

Of course, these are equivalent to F#, but very different in C#. Is there anything I can do to produce the C# I want? (F# 2.0.0.0)

As a quick hack, I rewrote my F# to:

```
let foo (f : Action<Action>) ((unit -> unit) -> unit)[] = ...
```

Then I just use `Head` in the C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `let foo x = fun () -> ...` then the F# compiler optimizes the code and compiles it as a method that takes two arguments (instead of a method returning function which is what you need). To get a function value as the result, you need to "do something" before returning the function:

```
// Will be compiled as method taking Action, FastFunc and returning void
let foo1(x : Action<Action>) : (unit -> unit) -> unit = 
  fun f -> f ()

// Will be compiled as method taking Action and returning FastFunc of FastFunc
let foo2(x : Action<Action>) : ((unit -> unit) -> unit) = 
  ignore ();
  fun f -> f ()
```

That said, exposing F# function type to C# in any way is a **bad pattern** and it shouldn't be done. When you have some F# API that is supposed to be used from C#, you should expose functions as delegates, so that C# consumers can use them naturally (without converting `Action` to F# function explicitly). It is generally easier to write the wrapping on the F# side.

Comment: @Thomas: Shouldn't that be (); fun f -> f()? Then it works perfectly. I am deliberately exposing native F# interfaces, and then writing conversion functions in F# (i.e. the above) so C# calls the F# function and the F# conversion. The reason is that C# is now considered legacy and will be gradually moved over to F#.

Comment: @NeilMitchell I meant to write `ignore ()`, but just writing `()` seems to work too! If you're eventually move to F#, then I guess it is fine (but I'll leave the warning note there for others). Congratulations to moving the C# bits to F# BTW!

Comment: @Thomas: I wonder if id $ fun f -> f() is the purest way of writing that (assuming the Haskell Prelude)

Comment: @NeilMitchell I guess writing `id <| fun f -> ...` has probably slightly nicer syntax than using `ignore` or semicolon. But really, anything will do - as long as the compiler does not see `let` immediately containing `fun`.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

1. Add a signature file, with `val foo : Action<Action> -> ((unit -> unit) -> unit)`.
2. Use a static member of a nominal type, rather than a let-bound value in a module.  That is, `static member foo (x:Action<Action>) : ((unit -> unit) -> unit) = ...`

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
open System 
let foo(x : Action<Action>) : (unit -> unit) -> unit = failwith "..."
```